# when running javac in a subprocess under ant in intellj, how does one make error messages clickable

Tags: java, ant, intellij-idea

That is ant's stderr and stdout are directed to the "messages" window when running an ant task inside the intellij IDE.  A powerful feature of an ide is it's ability to navigate you to the source file and location in which a compile or other error or log line occurred.

I am calling javac directly from a script called by an ant task spawned by the intellij IDE - I have not figured out a way to make the compile error messages "clickable" for navigation to the source files, where if I compile the same sources using the "make project" in intellij it's output window allows navigation to places where compile errors have occurred.

I have tried adding the '-emacs' and '-e' command line argument to ant in the build properties area with no effect.

The same is also desirable for exception stack traces that happen inside custom ant tasks or java apps run by an ant script.  I assume the source directories need to be active in the '.iml' configurations or sources for library jars within the project so the IDE knows where to find them and this is true for all the ones I am dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way of doing it fully automatically, but if you copy the stacktrace to the clipboard and then in IntelliJ use Analyse -> Stacktrace from the menu it'll give you a clickable stacktrace.

Comment: Awwwww - This seems like a serious design flaw for an IDE designed to run ant builds (or any script).  Most others I have used you can configure the logging format (file and line number in logged line) to make the IDE recognize it from the output window and make the lines referencing the file, line (and position) clickable for source navigation.